# Fundamantal group of a regular covering space

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $B$ be the space of figure $\infty$ (with $x$(the red circle) and $y$(the black one) as generators) and $E$ its covering space (in the picture below).

let $P_{*}: \Pi(E,a) \to \Pi(B,b) $ be the covering map which transformes $a_1 \to x$,$a_2 \to xyx^{-1}$,$a_3 \to x^2yx^{-2}$,$a_4 \to x^3yx^{-3}$,$a_5\to y^4y^{-4}=1$ so $P_{*}( \Pi(E,a))$ seems to be $F_4$.
I am locking at the spanning tree of the graph(marked blue in the image) and build the close paths according to their hats which means going on the spanning tree until i am on my generator and coming back so $ \hat{\gamma}_1=a_1 $ and $ \hat{\gamma}_1=\psi * a_2 * \overline{\psi}$ and so on ,so the last one is going on the spanning tree do $a_5$ and coming back from there i will get $1$

But if we calculate this graph fundamental group we will get $F_{8-4+1}=F_5$

Now the covering space is regular so $P_{*}( \Pi(E,a)$ should be normal $F_4$ is indeed normal in $F_2$ but $F_5$ isn't.

I understand that we should calculate $P_{*}( \Pi(E,a))$ according to the Base space $B$ which will give us another relation. But how can it be that $P_{*}( \Pi(E,a)$ is not isomorphic to $\Pi(E,a)$?

Can you explain why does the groups are different? how should i get $P_{*}( \Pi(E,a)$? and if they are  how  can it be that$P_{*}( \Pi(E,a)$ is not isomorphic to $\Pi(E,a)$?

[image]

Comment: if $a_1$ is mapped to $x$, then $a_2$ is mapped to $yxy^{-1}$ and $a_5$ is mapped to $y^4$.

Comment: Yes i am sorry i will edit it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The homomorphism $p_*$ induced by the covering space map is injective by the unique lifting property. So $\pi_1(E, a)$ is isomorphic to $p_*\left(\pi_1(E, a)\right)$.

The image of $a_5$ (the black circle) is $y^4$. Why do you think it's $y^4 y^{-4}$? The image of a nontrivial loop cannot be trivial by above.

The image of $a_2$ is $yxy^{-1}$. To see this, just map the loop to its image in $B$ and write the image in terms of $x$, $y$.

The subgroup $\langle x, yxy^{-1}, y^2xy^{-2}, y^3xy^{-3}, y^4\rangle$ is indeed normal in $\langle x, y\rangle$. This can be verified by direct inspection. Take the conjugate of each generator by $x$, $y$ and verify that the result is also an element of the same subgroup.

Comment: I think that you didnt understand my question ,the group is $F_5$  and the group of B is $F_2$ but as i know this covering space is regular so it means that the $P_{*}$ should be a normal sub group and if the group is $f_5$ it isnt.
i will edit my questio now, and hope to get an answer

Comment: @EliElizirov You still have mistakes in computing the subgroup. The subgroup is indeed normal and this can be easily seen once you have the correct generators. I've edited my answer.

Comment: @EliElizirov You're welcome!